# Problem with Toad -SQL- define-declare cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Hello everyone I have a problem, I normally use Oracle for the DB but recently I was forced to use TOAD and some query do not work anymore in particular it seems to dislike that I use the "define"  and  "declare cursor" can anyone help me?

Comment: You should include your code so people can help you. Also define is a sqlplus command, it's perfectly normal that is doesn't work in toad.

Comment: TOAD is a client application.  Like `SQL*Plus` or `SQL Developer`.  Oracle is a database server.  "I normally use Oracle" would mean that you are no longer using Oracle as a database server.  That's possible-- TOAD as a client application is perfectly able to connect to a SQL Server database or a MySQL database or most any other database.  But it's also possible that you mean to say that you are using TOAD as the client, you're still using an Oracle database, and you are encountering problems with various `SQL*Plus` commands in your scripts.

Comment: Good morning,
you are right i am new to the industry and i speak bad english.
I use an Oracle DB and as a Toad Client, I have been given some query that I should use designed for an Oracle Client (SQL Developer) but that don't work on Toad,
these queries contain the "Define" and the "declare cursor" which keep failing me and I don't know how to proceed to make these SqlPlus commands work on my Client.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer is a "dual mode" tool, in that it can run native SQL commands, but it can also run commands that would be part of SQL*Plus.  For example, "define" is not a SQL statement as such, but a keyword that can be used in SQL Plus / SQLcl (and hence SQL Developer).

To my knowledge, TOAD can use substitution variables and bind variables, but for DEFINE, you might need to rework your script.

Or just install SQL Developer (or even run it from a thumb drive)